# How are these infinite classes of groups of orders $6n$ and $8n$ called?

Tags: group-theory, reference-request, finite-groups

In the book *Gordon James, Martin Liebeck: Representations and Characters of Groups* the following three classes of groups are given
in a [series of exercises](http://books.google.com/books?id=PiJMr6kZP44C&pg=PA178), where the reader is asked to find all their irreducible representations and their character tables.$\newcommand{\inv}[1]{{#1}^{-1}}$

$$\begin{align*}
T_{4n}&=\langle a,b; a^{2n}=1, a^n=b^2, b^{-1}ab=a^{-1}\rangle\\
U_{6n}&=\langle a,b; a^{2n}=b^3=1, a^{-1}ba=b^{-1}\rangle\\
V_{8n}&=\langle a ,b; a^{2n}=b^4=1, ba=\inv a\inv b, \inv ba=\inv ab\rangle
\end{align*}$$

When solving these exercises we also find out that these group can be understood as  matrix groups:

- $T_{4n}$ as the group generated by $A=\begin{pmatrix}\varepsilon&0\\0&\varepsilon^{-1}\end{pmatrix}$ and $B=\begin{pmatrix}0&1\\\varepsilon^n&0\end{pmatrix}$, where $\varepsilon$ is some primitive $2n$-th root of unity;
- $U_{6n}$ as the group generated by $A=\begin{pmatrix}0&\varepsilon\\\varepsilon&0\end{pmatrix}$ and  $B=\begin{pmatrix}\omega&0\\0&\omega^2\end{pmatrix}$, where $\omega=e^{2\pi i/3}$ and $\varepsilon$ is a primitive $2n$/th root of unity;
- $V_{8n}$ as the group generated by $A=\begin{pmatrix}\eta&0\\0&-\inv\eta\end{pmatrix}$ and $B=\begin{pmatrix}0&1\\-1&0\end{pmatrix}$, where $\eta$ is some primitive $n$-th root of unity;
- $V_{8n}$ can also be obtained as the group generated by $A=\begin{pmatrix}\varepsilon&0\\0&\inv\varepsilon\end{pmatrix}$ and $B=\begin{pmatrix}0&1\\1&0\end{pmatrix}$, where $\varepsilon$ is some primitive $2n$-th root of unity.

The authors mention that the groups $T_{4n}$ are called [dicyclic groups](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dicyclic_group). They do not mention what the other two classes of groups are called.

I wonder whether these groups have some interesting properties and I would like to read a little more about them. Knowing the names for these classes group (if they have a name) would make searching for such information easier.

I have also made some quick Google Scholar Search for [U6n](http://scholar.google.sk/scholar?as_subj=eng&q=%22U6n%22+Group) and and [V8n](http://scholar.google.sk/scholar?as_subj=eng&q=Group+%22V8n%22). I have checked some of those papers (which I was able to access.) In those papers the authors refer to them simply as $U_{6n}$ and $V_{8n}$ and the book James-Liebeck is given as a reference, so this did not help me any further.

So my questions are:

> - What are the groups $U_{6n}$ and $V_{8n}$ called. (If they have some name?)
> - Where could I find more information about these groups?

Answer (score 3):

$U_{6n}$ belongs to so-called $Z$-metacyclic groups (H.S.M.Coxeter, W.O.J.Moser, Generators and relations for discrete groups, 1972).

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reference. I have just had looked there briefly and the books says that *Z-metacyclic groups* are groups for which both the commutator subgroup and the abelianization are cyclic. And it is also mentioned that Zassenhaus proved that all such groups can be obtained as
$\langle a,b;a^n=b^m=1, a^{-1}ba=b^r\rangle$ with $r^n\equiv 1\pmod m$ and $(r-1,m)=1$.
In the case of the groups I asked about I have such presentation with $n$ an even number, $m=3$, $r=2$; so this is indeed fulfilled for all groups of the form $U_{6n}$.

Comment: @Martin Sleziak: Maybe you can find something about $V_{6n}$ in this book.